How to get the plane of the hole using solidworks API?
I want to get the plane where the hole is located, I try to get the face through the feature, but it is the face inside the hole feature, not the plane where the hole is located. Later, I pass the plane of the special hole feature, and first call the AccessSelection method, but still can not get the plane where the hole is located.
                ModelDoc2 swModel = (ModelDoc2)swApp.ActiveDoc;
 if (feature.GetTypeName2() == "HoleWzd")
                    {
                        WizardHoleFeatureData2 wizardHoleFeature = (WizardHoleFeatureData2)feature.GetDefinition();                       
                     
                        if (wizardHoleFeature != null)
                        {
                            // Access selections
                            wizardHoleFeature.AccessSelections(swModel, null);

                            // Get the IWizardHoleFeatureData2 interface
                            // Try to get the face
                            Face2 endConditionFace = (Face2)wizardHoleFeature.Face;

                            if (endConditionFace != null)
                            {
                                // Successfully got the face, proceed with your operations
                                // e.g., getting face properties or geometry
                                Debug.Print("Successfully retrieved the face.");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // Face is still null, handle the case
                                Debug.Print("The end condition face is null.");
                            }

                            // Release selections
                            wizardHoleFeature.ReleaseSelectionAccess();


                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Debug.Print("Failed to find the feature.");
                        }


feature.getface is not what i want

Could you try something like IWizardHoleFeatureData2.GetSketchPoints then ISketchPoint.GetSketch then ISketch.GetReferenceEntity?

@bigcrazyal,Thank you very much for your comments. Through your guidance, I have successfully obtained the plane where the hole is located. You can turn comments into answers and I will mark!

To obtain the referenced plane, you'll have to dig down to the sketch created by the Hole Wizard Feature.
var swSketchPoints = IWizardHoleFeatureData2.GetSketchPoints();
var swSketch = swSketchPoints[0].GetSketch();
var refEntity = swSketch.GetReferenceEntity(out int lEntityType);

if (lEntityType == swSelectType_e.swSelDATUMPLANES)
{
    var swPlane = refEntity as IPlane;
}

Once you have the base entity, you can cast it to the type returned by the GetReferenceEntity as outlined on the SW swSelectType_e API help page
